# Jenkins AllView not called "All", can't rename

Tags: jenkins

I have no idea how this happened and can't seem to correct it via GUI.
Running Jenkins with folders-plugin.

Inside a folder, user has managed to rename the AllView to something else, then created a new ListView, called "All".

```
  <views>
    <hudson.model.ListView>
      <owner class="com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>All</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
      <includeRegex>.*</includeRegex>
      <recurse>false</recurse>
    </hudson.model.ListView>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>some_name</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <primaryView>All</primaryView>
```

No idea how they did that, but there's no option to rename the "AllView" in GUI. I can edit the ListView named "All" and change to something else, but cannot edit the "AllView" ('cos it's not a ListView). Ideas to fix ? Ideas to prevent future?

Not explained in https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Editing+or+Replacing+the+All+View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's just plain counter-intuitive ...

Achieved the results by:

- Create a temporary view (click the + ), type ListView (name temp)
- Set the new view (temp) as the default View
- Delete the AllView (named some_name)
- Delete the ListView (named "All")
- Create a new View (click the + ): you are presented with the option
  of view type "All", pick that, name it "All"
- Set the new "All" view as the Default
- delete the temp view
- optional: Make another ListView with name some_name and regex
  "`.*`"

It suggests a similar mechanism was used to make the wrongly named "AllView". Still need to understand how to prevent recurrence.